# C# .NET WinForms How do I copy instance of class from one List<class> to another List<class> using Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, clipboard

I'm writing a C# .NET WinForms app which contains two DataGridView controls, each with its own List:

DataGridView1, List1
DataGridView2, List2

FYI: DataItem is a class consisting of integers, strings, booleans, etc., and all items listed in each datagridview control are also listed in its corresponding List.

The user will right-click on a DataGridView1 and in the resulting context menu, click "Copy Item" to copy a DataItem from List1 to the clipboard...

```
    private void ctxtContextMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        int SelectedRowIndex = DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        if (ctxtCopyItem == e.ClickedItem)
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(List1[SelectedRowIndex]);
        }
        else if (ctxtPasteItem == e.ClickedItem)
        {
            PasteDataItem();
        }
     }
```

The user will then go to DataGridView2, right-click on it and in the context menu, click "Paste Item" to add that DataItem to DataGridView2 and to List2...

```
    private void PasteDataItem()
    {
        DataItem dataitem = new DataItem();
        dataitem = Clipboard.GetDataObject());   // This line is where the error occurs.
        List2.Add(dataItem); 
        UpdateDataGridView2();
     }
```

And here's the code for the context menu's Opening EventHandler...

```
    private void ctxtContextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // If clipboard contains a DataItem, enable ctxtPasteItem...
        if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() is DataItem)
            ctxPasteQuestion.Enabled = true;
    }
```

In the method "PasteDataItem()" above, an exception occurs:

System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataObject' to type 'DataItem'.

Apparently, I'm either not copying DataItem to the clipboard correctly or I'm not retrieving it from the clipboard correctly. One possible cause is that I'm not casting the DataItem properly. I haven't found any online tutorials on casting, copying and pasting an instance of a class using the clipboard. Is this even possible and if so, what's the right way to get that class instance to and from the Clipboard?

Comment: if both DataGridViews are in your app, why do you use clipboard? take a row from one and insert to another.

Comment: I'm thinking about just passing a item as a parameter, but I want to use the clipboard in case the user wants to pass an item from DataGridView1 in one instance of the app to another similar DataGridView in another instance of the app. That's kind of weird, I know, but I'd like the user to be able to do that.

Comment: You can still pass data between instances of your app by tcp/ip , named pipes etc. All you need is to serialize data from one end and deserialize on the other. So you still do no need clipboard. But OK, do it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

*Clipboard.GetDataObject()* returns an *IDataObject* and not your stored data directly. Then, you can use that returned *IDataObject* to access your stored data.
Potentially what you want is the following:

```
var clipboardDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
dataitem = (DataItem)clipboardDataObject.GetData(typeof(DataItem));
```

Although ideally you'll make that code more robust to handle errors and such.
Additionally, this means that your code on *ctxtContextMenu_Opening* may not be working as expected either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Fredy. Your code example seems to be what I'll need to do to paste the item from the clipboard into a datagridview. How do I write code for copying an item TO the clipboard?

Comment: What you showed above is not working? Does it throw any exception?